# Wrong result of sizeof

Tags: php, arrays, sizeof

I have several files in a folder and i want to count them.

```
$folder = "images";
$allPics = scandir($folder);
$result = sizeof($allPics);
echo $result;
```

The result is 350 but it should be 348. I don't get it why it is showing me the result +2?

Am i missing something?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

When looking at the documentation you can see the function return both '.' and '..', that's why you're having 2 more than you should have.

You can use this:

```
array_diff(scandir($folder), array('..', '.'));
```

To get rid of the dots you don't wanna have.

Comment: oh man, how could i forgot these dots. Thanks to all of you. I will mark this as answer in some mintues. (you guys are really fast). :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the unix system and it have, 2 pointers in each directory, the pointer for the parent dirrectory that usualy is notted with `..` and the pointer to the current directory that is notted as `.`